# ¿Cómo contar archivos que pertenecen a usuarios en bash?

Tags: bash, shell, búsquedas

Necesito mostrar los nombres de los usuarios que sean propietarios de un número de archivos mayor a un número que le paso por parámetro.

Mi primer intento para ello es:

```
stat -c %U $(find /home) | sort | uniq -c
```

Ello muestra los usuarios y los archivos que tienen desde /home. El problema es cómo poder manejar ese número de archivos para comparar con una variable y mostrar el usuario si cumple la condición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que puede ser más útil utilizar la *flag* `-user <usuario>`  que proporciona `find`:

```
find -user <usuario>
```

Esto te devolverá el listado de ficheros. Como el nombre en sí no es importante para ti, puedes escribir algo así como un punto para cada uno y luego contarlos:

```
find -user <usuario> -printf . | wc -c
```

Con esto obtendrás el número exacto.

Si lo que quieres es contar este número para todos los usuarios, puede ser útil recorrer `/etc/passwd` y hacerlo para cada uno.

Por ejemplo:

```
limite=100  # elige tú el valor límite
while IFS=" " read -r usuario dir;
do
    contador=$(find "$dir" -user "$usuario" -printf . | wc -c)
    if [ "$contador" -ge "$limite" ]; then
        echo "usuario $usuario tiene $contador ficheros en su directorio "$dir"
    fi
done < <(awk -F: '{print $1, $6}' /etc/passwd)
```

Probablemente quieras añadir más condiciones a tu comando `find`. Por ejemplo, `-type f` para contar solamente los ficheros (y no los directorios, enlaces, etc).

Comment: Ha funcionado a las mil maravillas, al final llegué a la misma conclusión que tú al cabo de un largo tiempo. La única diferencia es que le pasas por entrada lo del awk mientras que yo le paso directamente el /etc/passwd.

Comment: @CarlosMartelLamas qué bien que te fuera útil. Sí, paso a través de awk para ofrecer el 1º y 6º campos. Podría haber hecho `< /etc/passwd` y coger esos campos posteriormente, pero me pareció más limpio así.